# pack (type erase) a random number generator

Tags: c++, c++11, random

The C++11 std library has several random number generators (RNG), each implementing the concept [UniformRandomNumberGenerator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UniformRandomNumberGenerator). These can then be used as argument for random distributions, see also [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for an overview.

The advantage of this design is that the choice of the underlying RNG engine is de-coupled from its application. However, the design also requires the definition (not merely the declarations) of all calls to the RNG to be available (if the RNG type is to remain unspecified as template parameter). Thus, in

```
struct complicated_random_distribution
{
  /*
     some data and auxiliary methods here
  */
  // complicated; may call RNG::operator() many times
  template<typename RNG>
  some_type operator()(RNG&gen) const;
};
```

the member `operator()` cannot be straightforwardly implemented in a separate compilation unit (CU), but must be available in the same header file (or one `#include`d from it).

For a separate implementation, one ideally would want some way to pack a RNG in the same way as `std::function<>` packs any callable object.
(Simply using `std::function` and providing the values for `RNG::min()` and `RNG::max()` as arguments to a function defined in a separate CU is restrictive and will not allow to use, say, `std::uniform_real_distribution<>` inside).

How can this be done? Are implementations for this available? Will the std library provide this in the future? Or am I after a red herring?

---

*Edit* Random number generators are required to have `static` members `min()` and `max()`, making type-erasure hard or impossible (GNU's libstdc++ doesn't make this assumption and a type erasure with non-static members `min()` and `max()` works, but not with LLVM's libc++, which uses the standard required `static` members). Is there a way to still solve this problem? If not, doesn't this imply that the C++ standard has a botched interface for random number generators?

Comment: You can easily implement that out of line, the definition just needs to be in the header file. Would that really be so bad?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "type erase", not "pack". Also how would you handle `min()` and `max()`? Do all URNG's have the same range? I assume no?

Comment: @Walter You sure can: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47941423fc589739 Well, maybe we are talking about different things.

Comment: Also "... to be fully inlined". No, it just requires them to be implemented in a header. Just because a function is implemented in the header doesn't mean it's inlined.

Comment: @Barry and @BaummitAugen Okay, I meant *not implemented in a header* rather than out-of-line. Edited the question. And Barry, yes I know that I can implement this via type erase (just did), but `min()` and `max()` must be kept, because they are, of course, returning different values for different RNGs.

Comment: Random number generators are usually extremely low level operations.  One should be careful about abstracting low level operations, because the it adds load to every abstraction added above it.  Is your goal to just type erase the generator for the purpose of a particular distribution?  That is relatively easy.

Comment: @Yakk yes, currently I only want to erase the generator for one particular distribution, but inside that distribution's `operator()` I want to use `std::uniform_real_distribution<>` in a separate compilation unit.

Comment: Is the only use you are going to put the Generator passed in a `std::uniform_real_distribution<>`?  Do you know, before hand, how many calls to the uniform real distribution you are going to make, exactly or approximately?

Comment: @Yakk what made you delete your answer?

Comment: Wrap the RNG in an `independent_bits_engine`, and type erase that.

Comment: @T.C. Could you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapt the RNG with an `independent_bits_engine`, and type erase the adapted RNG. You have full knowledge of what the `independent_bits_engine`'s `min()` and `max()` are.

Here's a sketch:

```
struct RNG_wrapper {
    using result_type = std::uint32_t;
    static constexpr result_type min() { return 0; }
    static constexpr result_type max() { return 0xFFFFFFFF; }

    template<class RNG>
    using my_engine_type = std::independent_bits_engine<RNG, 32, result_type>;

    template<class RNG,
             class = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<RNG>, RNG_wrapper>{}>>
    RNG_wrapper(RNG&& r)
        : rng(my_engine_type<std::decay_t<RNG>>(std::forward<RNG>(r))) {}

    result_type operator()() { return rng(); }
    std::function<result_type()> rng;
};
```

Comment: Okay now I understand the idea: by using an `independent_bits_engine` you can make the `min` and `max` static, because they only depend on the static number of bits .. clever!

Comment: Somehow, I do not like that we cannot infer max from `my_engine_type`. Perhaps it would be a good idea to allow min and max to be non-static.

Answer (score 1):

This works in clang and gcc (with libstdc++), but this is not strictly a `UniformRandomNumberGenerator`, for the noted reason that `min` and `max` are not static.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class AnyUniformRandomNumberGenerator
{
    T mMin;
    T mMax;
    std::function<T()> mValue;
public:

    using result_type = T;

    template<typename UniformRandomNumberGenerator>
    AnyUniformRandomNumberGenerator(UniformRandomNumberGenerator uniformRandomNumberGenerator) :
    mMin(UniformRandomNumberGenerator::min()),
    mMax(UniformRandomNumberGenerator::max()),
    mValue([=]() mutable { return uniformRandomNumberGenerator(); })
    {}

    T operator()()
    {
        return mValue();
    }

    T min()
    {
        return mMin;
    }

    T max()
    {
        return mMax;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::default_random_engine rng;
    AnyUniformRandomNumberGenerator<decltype(rng())> any{rng};

    assert(any() <= any.max());
    assert(any() >= any.min());

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist{1, 6};

    std::cout << dist(any);
}
```

GCC:
http://rextester.com/ANAP79935

clang
http://rextester.com/YCIIR21607

Comment: @Walter It is a libstdc++ thing I think. If you change to libstdc++ in apple clang I'm guessing it will work.

Comment: @Walter I think rextester uses libstdc++ with Clang too.

Comment: This is essentially what I tried initially, but what doesn't compile with `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11`. Your use of `libstdc++` made it work, but that's not standard compliant.

Comment: I used this in gcc 10, broken in gcc 11.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more generic implementation that lets you specify the min and max values freely. Besides, it does not copy the wrapped engine, unlike `independent_bits_engine` and `std::function` as suggested by [@2756719](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32555276/4820605). The later property is important as it allows the user to carry around its original engine without having to wrap it explicitly. A lightweight temporary wrapper will be implicitly instantiated when pass to the method. Since it holds a reference to the original engine, its internal state will be updated as it is supposed to be. In addition, `std::function_ref` can be inlined way more easily by the compiler than `std::function`, ultimately resulting in compile-time templating. To achieve this, it relies on `std::function_ref`, which is part of the upcoming C++26 standard.

```
template<typename ResultType, 
         ResultType min_ = std::numeric_limits<ResultType>::min(), 
         ResultType max_ = std::numeric_limits<ResultType>::max()> 
class uniform_random_bit_generator_ref : private std::function_ref<ResultType()>
{
public:
    using result_type = ResultType;

    template<typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::bool_constant<(
        std::decay_t<F>::min() == min_ && std::decay_t<F>::max() == max_ 
        )>::value>>
    constexpr uniform_random_bit_generator_ref(F && f) noexcept : 
    function_ref<result_type()>(f)
    {
    }

    using function_ref<result_type()>::operator();

    static constexpr result_type min() noexcept { return min_; }
    static constexpr result_type max() noexcept { return max_; }
};
```

For completeness, [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAnLGkAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XEJCnUNTdmtQ109xaUDAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMwcjeWADUJutuyEP4ggfYJhoAghtbO5j7h8SG6Kgs55c3ZpsM2157BzcTiGxEwrA%2B11uv3ujzcVC8v2qYghXx%2BfwBhwIAE9EpgAPoEZ6EBQoz5Q9EPQHYPDARgAeg8oNJ1zpdMeABEDpz1tzeVz%2BTyBXzBSLhWKhRLRZLxVKpZDrgRMCxEgZFYDsbjmGxdgAxc77a7bJgKBS7eGI9J40FUA5WeVXRXK1WYdU4xisB4AJVIuw17rYADog7srsRgCT1tgDVcjSazQiHJbrYDPRBQ%2BGgwHZvqyQB2O1XRJeCK0PDIECfXZV3ZoBhDTCqRLEeMWgRWzBUCC1oYtxNt5OHVPphSZ7OR/ZmABsu2ICAUs12DFQDZWiQIHN2WCoTC8tAItrJ12rvqVKqYasxbq1Dx1Pr9143JxAIHdJfxeCoBMBleP1afIDwBQ8XNPsGDxAA3QE9XHcxJ1gn9f12f9ALxYJwNQUQ3ytCCUx9W8QzDEcgw%2BSMUWPbtFUbZsQOqdtOx1XYACozQXJcV0wNddhAaNj1QCJtDxLsBCGPFRCGQF0LwdBGPOCBQWCRViCbTACFE4190OCjdkk9AmNkqhZkMnjqxMfMEN/URaFoCImGQABrPENxMABWKxnPZCAdKY3Y%2BO0H1h0zXZ6nDBcAFp9U9fYzKPRDf1BAglgYJCCHQZ80NQOzMAgczYt/Rj5MEaJlNUsSNLce8PWS1KQCYdB0DxZIFOiL9Dmgi5IwgXz5hy3K/xS59%2BGIAB3ep0EBYdZOC%2BdRwPGLENM7kC2PBbDyuY9HTPC9yqvSr8Iq7UuSq59X3oVDPzKnqqzAMBkKAhQPRww5/ywUQsRatw2p9Gikw7HMp3gubf2u268TYEpmsawriEetxnswV73rav64P%2BwHjxB9LMNO6HIMHPD/MIzMSPai5AYohsm17WjrQgBj4KnFjF2XVRV3XbjzN8wSKLU8TDh0mSOomRxkB5sqtK8gXsAgf9avQUETVQTsDMMhdzNMpbYss6zbIcpzXJcjyJZ8/iCYzYMprCiKoo13qZxUxKjoAhh0My7K0dtpihbLUXXU1SqZbqhrUCa6GyqRjqutIS7ev/QaRuIMbDgmjqLZm9Ybd/Fb07V3NOXtcjhMoynvv7X7BzTQmgzHKMAbW6tUFxZ4iGILkhLrdcS7Agc3CHSus2Rmc51Y5nWY3Lcdz3WabkBjbnV9/0bzvHaDp5R2Tvfc7v3dq6bv6gC7oe3HYb3l6mDesPzi%2BhNqbLkmyOrTu6JTCuzf7mCGYb6JzxIVu6f%2BhmDJM3YpxQ6WB6AXgLOZSKn8m4kAgLMF%2BREAxBUIguLSOcM7Hnig7LWNl7KCU5j6WOJB46JzcMnKWqcq5T2WrnVaTY8DgXPOwH8RtOY0N2JFCAjFcE6zxAgiWpskFjkgXQ7O9pWQhjqmkAQYhNyYHQF4UCuxgBeCkpgEkCpTxz0vH7bUSNriPxpgxRiltxxGLLh9EikCWRsmlPY2UMonEOOcY4lx7j7Sz2YfPB8noNG7gIAAFTdD6aOnD/F7mCbiXYLBgiOUOv%2BBgPhoje1LLEggEYe4RKCW6c4z5YkMHgaE7eVY/EKACVEh4LAmCqHiavRJyTiCpLwOkzJZSKm5MjPkmp8CcyGgMHGBEH4SAsCtC8N4eIIiEDxLSEIsDobWi4rsBhTDFRUx%2BjaQc2TKm9NIpCaKhZiylnLOZLwqQjB23KXuAkboNztMiZ0mxdcqxeK2vtRevpl6UnqXvdeZ13r/giKgTwolC6GDKm7Z5v44YIwvl0kABT4EckOgU%2BJ/9pwwrPojPJCKemq1FDEmp8SSnV2fEw7wLpSJ7KheTKiuwhmDVGc8BgrxRlTNUrMr%2Bzc6K0wnCjacgC2Isw4mzYyVYLGbLcPLAJNzcS7KlgZDBOc87TyhWc4IwB1ml0ldK65fp5XPhgd/YguynnozqMLGshcKbNl1apP0MTghIqFaPdWdsErECSqi20UUVXmvPGWK17cbWXJlQ66pqhnUjxFdbd1DsI14h9StfZi1VqfCoLQVA54mbEGqbQNuPYGUjLGSyiZ7KZmMC5SQJ%2Bhw1GCHWGYFqNcGbAGzPsjOiSRliDxPgEEeAIheGqICDNWaNJRjGvmZyAYNA%2BjMNOrOGdsGes3NAEReYVWrQUoSp1babgHPNdVFgBAuDxHWLmFRjAG3qw0Au8y/40CDthICHNeboCXrMPitwz7/yuFoBwqs97Fjrm/IcF9Yg30MAbZ%2B79vyWV/vEaqrB9tl03oQwtDg8xaCcGcrwPwHAtCkFQJwL9lhrBIUWMsSk3weCkAIJoDD8w7IgGcjOrDHBJC4fo4RzgvAFAgBnXR/DGHSBwFgDARAKA3iJDoNEcglA0DKhkzEI0RguAseNEoBofA6CKT4xACIXGpnMGIFiTgNGjP1CxAAeX4vDQTNGFNsEEFZhgtBTNCdIFgAdwA3BiFoHx7gvAsDVKMOIDz%2BBQSJnAhorjDZ4aDtWARpqbGaOlgiM8EzHgsBccJC0szwmM1MHDAANTwJgIaVnNT5ZkIIEQYh2BSBq/IJQaguO6FaAYIwKBrDWH0P2vjsBrwvhpIwUg0WYgcHWJILQhlCNrnSAF0KJwuSmFI5YLg57QpWZo6gcbTSsADaKXYOz6QXAstGC0UggRgi9HBjEVouQZEZE8M0HIKQntTD6PdtoJ2BCdBGC9sYP3QL/e6Dd6Y/RxjDEaIDy7EwGifbuxIeYCgKMrGR/obDnGPNEY4LsVQAAOScoVJySBrJ1zVanp3Tt2BADT0Rqjzlp7gQgJAJzrC4LMXggmZuMeY6xzgHHSAsH56QPDBHce8f47R%2Bj8xRMSaA0WAgcmhKKfoMQUIHpOCE%2BJ6TlRyBkC7C4HOmjCjWf7b0PwWrlkGvSCt81lQ6gPPtdIENZ4iR8uYax2LrjuOrODqVz5Kg%2BOick7JypynU6NA07pyaBnC2FwQA8Gr6I7POfc9l/MBAYIsAxCKWxoXIuWM%2B5xzx2w0uecMdIEx4vbH1jY4l2Xyvs22NmAb7wSXMuhOzfG6kZwkggA%3D%3D%3D) is a complete Godbolt example that adheres C++17 standard by shipping its own implementation of `std::function_ref`.