# Custom UniformRandomBitGenerator fails to compile

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to create a wrapper around the random number generation sources defined in C++  header that return uint_fast32_t, such that one base class can store a pointer to any RNG (std::mt19937, std::default_random, etc).  This is for the purpose of storing random number generation sources as class members without having to make the class a template class.  The solution I came up with: I defined an abstract base class RNGSource that implements the C++ [UniformRandomBitGenerator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UniformRandomBitGenerator) standard.  Then, I defined a template class RNGSourceWrap that implements RNGSource, takes some C++ rng source as a parameter, and implements the RNGSource functions to forward calls to the underlying C++ rng stored.  The code is as follows:

```
#ifndef RANDOM_H
#define RANDOM_H
#include <cstdint>


class RNGSource
{
    public: 
        virtual ~RNGSource() = default;
        typedef uint_fast32_t result_type;
        virtual result_type operator() () = 0;
        virtual result_type min() const = 0;
        virtual result_type max() const = 0;
};


template <class Generator>
class RNGSourceWrap : public RNGSource
{
    public:
        RNGSourceWrap(Generator* rng);

        virtual result_type operator() () override;
        virtual result_type min() const override;
        virtual result_type max() const override;
        Generator* rng() const;

    private:
        Generator* rngVal;
};

template <class Generator>
RNGSourceWrap<Generator>::RNGSourceWrap(Generator* rng)
    : rngVal(rng) { }

template <class Generator>
typename RNGSourceWrap<Generator>::result_type 
RNGSourceWrap<Generator>::operator() () { return rngVal->operator() (); }

template <class Generator>
typename RNGSourceWrap<Generator>::result_type 
RNGSourceWrap<Generator>::min() const { return rngVal->min(); }

template <class Generator>
typename RNGSourceWrap<Generator>::result_type 
RNGSourceWrap<Generator>::max() const { return rngVal->max(); }

template <class Generator>
Generator* RNGSourceWrap<Generator>::rng() const { return rngVal; }
#endif // RANDOM_H
```

I wrote a small main to test funtionality:

```
#include "random.h"
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng;

    RNGSource* rngWrap = new RNGSourceWrap<std::mt19937>(&rng);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distro(1, 6);
    int myInt = distro(*rngWrap);

    std::cout << myInt << std::endl;

    delete rngWrap;

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and runs with no warnings or errors when compiled with Linux g++ and MinGW using c++ 14 standard.  However, it generates errors when compiled with MSVC (using Visual Studio 2017 Community):

```
1>------ Build started: Project: RNGTestApp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\xutility(3479): error C2352: 'RNGSource::max': illegal call of non-static member function
1>[PATH REMOVED]\visual studio 2017\projects\rngtestapp\random.h(14): note: see declaration of 'RNGSource::max'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\xutility(3476): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::_Rng_from_urng<unsigned int,_Engine>::_Rng_from_urng(_Urng &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Engine=RNGSource,
1>            _Urng=RNGSource
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\random(2353): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Rng_from_urng<unsigned int,_Engine>::_Rng_from_urng(_Urng &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Engine=RNGSource,
1>            _Urng=RNGSource
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\random(2353): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Rng_from_urng<unsigned int,_Engine>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Engine=RNGSource
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\random(2312): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int std::uniform_int<_Ty>::_Eval<_Engine>(_Engine &,_Ty,_Ty) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int,
1>            _Engine=RNGSource
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\random(2312): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int std::uniform_int<_Ty>::_Eval<_Engine>(_Engine &,_Ty,_Ty) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int,
1>            _Engine=RNGSource
1>        ]
1>[PATH REMOVED]\visual studio 2017\projects\rngtestapp\main.cpp(11): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int std::uniform_int<_Ty>::operator ()<RNGSource>(_Engine &) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int,
1>            _Engine=RNGSource
1>        ]
1>[PATH REMOVED]\visual studio 2017\projects\rngtestapp\main.cpp(11): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int std::uniform_int<_Ty>::operator ()<RNGSource>(_Engine &) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int,
1>            _Engine=RNGSource
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\xutility(3479): error C2352: 'RNGSource::min': illegal call of non-static member function
1>[PATH REMOVED]\visual studio 2017\projects\rngtestapp\random.h(13): note: see declaration of 'RNGSource::min'
1>Done building project "RNGTestApp.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Given that this does compile using Linux g++ and MinGW, and appears to qualify as implementing the UniformRandomBitGenerator standard, is this a compiler bug?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571141/pack-type-erase-a-random-number-generator/32555276#32555276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you understood the wording of the UniformRandomBitGenerator concept wrong. `result_type`, `max`, and `min` are all to be defined `static`, which your implementation fails to do. While the word 'static' is not used in the formulation, have a close look at how the expressions are written.

In you wrapper you can wrap accordingly:

```
template <class Generator>
typename RNGSourceWrap<Generator>::result_type 
RNGSourceWrap<Generator>::min() const { return Generator::min(); }
```

… and declare the respective methods static. However if somebody calls `RNGSource::min()` it will be ineffective.

Comment: That makes sense (and unfortunately breaks the concept of what I'm doing), however out of curiosity, despite the fact that they are to be static, why does the code compile on at least 2 C++ compilers when they are not?

Comment: Aren't you using GCC on MinGW? Then it would be one compiler. This is just a random detail of the standard library. If you have an object `rng` of your random number generator `Rng` at hands, you can either write `rng->max()` or `Rng::max()`. It seems GCC developers chose the first option, and MSVC the second. Only the second fails if `max()` is not static.

Comment: That makes sense.  Unfortunately declaring the respective methods static doesn't do me a lot of good, because of exactly the reason you mentioned -- if someone calls RNGSource::min() it would fail (which something like std::uniform_int_distribution would do if I tried to pass it a reference to an RNGSource as in my main() example).  Even so, it answers the question perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: If you consider the answer helpful, please accept it, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of selecting one from several possible and predefined random generators at runtime and use it in functions that expect such a generator. After a long time I found

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

class RNGbase {

public:
    virtual ~RNGbase() = default;
    typedef uint32_t result_type;             //type has to be hardcoded in superclass?
    virtual result_type operator() () = 0;    //will be overridden in subclass
    inline static result_type (*min) ();      //function pointer will be set in subclass constructor
    inline static result_type (*max) ();      //function pointer will be set in subclass constructor
};

template <class R> class RNG : public RNGbase {

public:
    using result_type = typename R::result_type;

    R r;

    RNG() {
        RNGbase::min = R::min;
        RNGbase::max = R::max;
    }

    result_type operator() () override {
        return r();
    }
};


int main() {
    //dynamically create generator
    std::unique_ptr<RNGbase> rng = std::make_unique<RNG<std::random_device>>();

    //use generator for sampling
    std::vector<int> values { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    std::vector<int> samples(2);
    std::sample(values.cbegin(), values.cend(), samples.begin(), samples.size(), *rng);
    std::cout << "samples " << samples[0] << " " << samples[1] << std::endl;

    //use generator for number distributions
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distro(1, 6);
    std::cout << distro(*rng) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```